# Tabs on plain URL not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

Can someone give me an idea how to make this work?

**EXAMPLE OF THE PROBLEM:**
http://jsfiddle.net/j47nd/3/

This is the default way Bootstrap is actually doing it, but there is no other example or way to do it with simple links. I tried several solutions presented here on StackOverflow but non of them treat just pure links.

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tab-panes need the id, not the first nested div:

http://jsfiddle.net/j47nd/7/

bad:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" >
    <div id="tab1"><h1>This is tab 1</h1></div>
</div>
```

good:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
    <div ><h1>This is tab 1</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Malk, thank you! I was looking at the code and couldnt wrap my head around it. I dont know how I missed that. I checked and I checked and I checked the code but could never... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle to the following: http://jsfiddle.net/j47nd/9/

Essentially you had it almost correct but you had:

```
<div class="tab-pane">
   <div id="tab1"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
</div>
```

Should be:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
   <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
</div>
```

You only really had one issue here. Which was putting the id in a child <div>. The javascript shows and hides the <div> with the ID which was going to remain hidden under the tab-pane div which is hidden already.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Kris, thank you as well! I was looking at the code but I couldnt find what was wrong with it. Thank you.